# ...is computed by counting each test score twice that of a quiz score,

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, predeterminers

An excerpt from a textbook....

Two tests, a quiz, and a final exam are given...
Assume that the instructor has decided that a student's course average **is computed by counting each test score twice that of a quiz score**, and that the final exam score counts three times as much as a test score.

> A) Is **twice** an adverb or a predeterminer?

> B) What is the meaning of the word **that**?

> C) How about **counting each test score which is twice a quiz score**? Does it have the same meaning as the original sentence?

Putting it in a mathematical way is like

*y* = 2*u*/11 + 2*v*/11 + 1*w*/11 + 6*z*/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase is very badly written, and I can't say for sure that it is grammatical. It seems the intended meaning is "each quiz score counts for a certain amount, each test score counts for twice that amount, and the final exam counts for three times as much as a test score (six times as much as a quiz)."

One problem here is that the word "that" here is used to replace some noun, but there is no noun available in the sentence for it to replace, which is very confusing to read. A clearer way of writing that sentence would be to replace "that of" with "as much as" (similar to the second comparison in the sentence).